# Put a Font Awesome icon dynamically on input text background using React and react-fa

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, font-awesome

I'm using `ReactJs` and `react-fa` to access Font Awesome icons. I need to put one of the icons inside a text input dynamically.

Here is my code:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import { Icon } from 'react-fa';

    import '../index.css';

    class SearchInput extends Component {

        static propTypes = { 
          onKeyUp: PropTypes.object,
          placeholder: PropTypes.placeholder,
          iconName: PropTypes.string
        };


        handleKeyUp = (content) => {

            console.log(content);

        }

        render() {

                let icon = <Icon name={this.props.iconName} />;

                let extra = {
                    backgroundImage: icon
                }

                return (
                    <input className='ux-search-input' style={extra} type='text' onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp} placeholder={this.props.placeholder} />
                    );
        }
    };

    export default SearchInput;
```

This does not work - no icons at all. Repair that in that case I have no URLs to match, as the `icon` variable will be a ReactJs component.

Comment: You're specifying an `<Icon />` tag as a backgroundImage value which is wrong. The backgroundImage value should be a url string and not a tag.

Comment: Fine, but I have no URL, as Icon is another ReactJs component that loads font-awesome icons.... That´s the trick of the question....

Answer (score 0):

react-fa is a React component, and it renders as html like `<i class="fa fa-name" />`, so you can't use it as a style. You should use something like this:

```
      return (
          <span>
             { icon }
             <input className='ux-search-input' style={extra} type='text' onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp} placeholder={this.props.placeholder} />
          </span>
          );
```

and add some styling to match proper icon position.

Comment: Wrong. This will not put the icon as the input background image, but outside the input....

Comment: Of course, this will not put icon as input background image. <Icon> is not an image, it's a component so you cannot use it as background image. And icon has no image at all, it uses font, but not an image. So use this method and move the icon inside input via css.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using React component, try using a regular icon tag  in front of the input field, and then use css to move the icon to the appropriate position.

For example:

JSX:

```
<i class={this.props.iconName} id="icon" />
```

CSS:

```
#icon {
  // Adjust margins and position to fit the input background
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```